# How to build a struct in root struct for FlatBuffers C++

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

Seems like the flatbuffers authors missed an example for the Equipment struct in Monster and that would help here.

I have a struct (Message) within a root struct (MyProjectRootMessage).
This seems to be the way to do it from the monster.fbs example.

```
enum MyProjectMsgType : byte { Message1=0, Message2 }

union Message { Message1, Message2 }

table MyProjectRootMessage {
    msg_type:MyProjectMsgType;
    message:Message;
}

table Message1 {
}

table Message2 {
}
```

But I'm trying to construct it in C++ and am getting an error for the message types.  It says `message` is of type `Offset<Message1>` when it should be of type `Message`.

```
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;

auto message = Message1Builder(builder).Finish();

auto rootMessage = CreateMyProjectRootMessage(builder, MyProjectMsgType_Message1, message); // complains on message here
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `enum MyProjectMsgType`, the `union` already generates a type enum for you.

`Offset<Message1>` has a method that converts it into a generic offset suitable for use with unions.

Comment: Ok I think I got what the schema should look like.  But what is the method, im not seeing much available? What does that code look like?

Comment: I should just be `.Union()` on the Offset<T>: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/include/flatbuffers/buffer.h#L30